How can I use string as return type in Native AOT?
I am a beginner in AOT. Recently I followed a tutorial to try it.
Here is the code of the tutorial:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Add")]
        public static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;        
    }
}

And it runs well.
Now I want to return a string and I code it like this:
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Test")]
public static string Test()
{
    return "Test";
}

Then VS reports an error:

Cannot use 'string' as a return type on a method attributed with
'UnmanagedCallersOnly'.

What's wrong with it? How can I return a string in Native AOT?

string is a .NET object type.  Native code doesn't understand .NET objects.  You may need to use a char[].

@TimRoberts After I change it to public static char[] Test(), it reports similar errors:Cannot use 'char[]' as a return type on a method attributed with 'UnmanagedCallersOnly'.

How about byte[]?

@shingo The same error also.

Because the method will be called from unmanaged code, which cannot directly handle managed types like string, the [UnmanagedCallersOnly] attribute in Native AOT can only be applied to methods that use simple data types like integers or pointers, which is the cause of the problem you are experiencing.
You need to ensure that memory is managed appropriately and return a pointer to a string in order to retrieve a string from an unmanaged function. When collaborating with unmanaged code, a typical method is to utilize IntPtr or char*. Here's a quick tutorial on using Marshal to return a string.The managed string can be changed to an unmanaged one using StringToHGlobalAnsi:
    using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ClassLibrary1

{

    public class Class1

    {

        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Test")]

        public static IntPtr Test()

        {

            string managedString = "Test";

            // Convert the managed string to an unmanaged pointer

            IntPtr unmanagedString = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString);

            return unmanagedString;

        }

    }

}


BTW, I found that there are many different types to convert to IntPtr, including Ansi you provided, and BSTR. This is my first time to come into contact with this. What are the differences between these?

The various kinds, such as Ansi, BSTR, and others, are used to convert a managed string into formats that unmanaged code understands. i can short them as follows:
Ansi (Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi): This function converts a managed string to an unmanaged string encoded in ANSI format. Each character is normally 1 byte. Used when working with unmanaged code that expects strings encoded in ANSI (as is frequent with earlier APIs). Unicode characters that require more than one byte are not proper.



BSTR (Marshal.StringToBSTR): This function converts a managed string to a BSTR (Binary String) format, which is commonly used in COM. Used for COM interop or when unmanaged code requires strings in BSTR format. It is not extensively used outside of COM interoperability, hence it may be unnecessary in most circumstances.



I see. Thank you very much.

I would mention the need to release any allocated memory. For someone unfamiliar with native code that might not be obvious. And to document ownership etc to avoid mistakes.
